# PayPal Rest API error that sum does not add up but it does

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PayPal Rest API (SDK for Java) and when I submit a payment for excution (i.e. before the redirect) I get the error:

```
  Excetpion e [{
  "field": "transactions[0]",
  "issue": "Item amount must add up to specified amount subtotal (or total if amount details not specified)"
}]]]
```

However the numbers are as follows (copy from my debug log) and add up and particularly the price of all items (there is only one) is exactly the subtotal

```
[[ tranaction t total 24.57]]
[[ tranaction t subtotal 19.8]]
[[ tranaction t tax 3.92]]
[[tranaction t shipping 0.85]]
[[tranaction t item[0] price 19.8]]
```

Anybody an idea whats up there?
Cheers
Tom

Comment: Can you post the full payment object that you are setting in the request please? If you have any item_list objects set in there that will help as well.

Comment: Yes, need to see the actual request sent to PayPal.  You'll probably find the numbers in it aren't what you expect.  This error doesn't come back unless itemamt + shippingamt + handlingamt + taxamt do not equal the total amt.

Comment: @JonathanLeBlanc  thanks. That already helped. I found that I have a quantity 2 set and payPal interprets the price as per each item and not as the value for the 2 items combined. So I just modified that accordindly and it works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is that I had below values  and paypal then interprets the price as per item and not for the 2 items combined. Adaption then worked

```
"item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "PRODUCT_6",
            "quantity": "2",
            "price": "19.8",
            "currency": "EUR"
          }
        ]
      }
```